# pandas check if Series values are in Interval

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

Is there a nicer way to check if pandas Series values are in pandas Interval:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
x = pd.Series(np.linspace(4.0,7.8,num=20))
i = pd.Interval(5.0, 6.0, closed='left')

result = (i.left<=x) & (x<i.right)
```

Is it possible to compute result less explicitly, i.e. without accessing `i.left`, `i.right`, `i.closed`?
Something like `x.isin(i)` or `x in i`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What you wrote is the fastest solution since it used vectorized code. You can use `x.map(i.__contains__)` but this is about 300x slower on a large series

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.cut()` for that:

```
bins=[5.0,6.0]
pd.cut(x,bins,right=False).dropna()
5    [5.0, 6.0)
6    [5.0, 6.0)
7    [5.0, 6.0)
8    [5.0, 6.0)
9    [5.0, 6.0)
```